# Trying to resize a lvm

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted, lvm

So I used Gparted to decrease the size of a partition. The partition has a minimum size of 206598 and a maximum size of 476939. I try to resize the partition to be 206598, but when i do. I get the following error. I tried to use pvmove, but I get PE range errors, so I'm obviously not doing the right values.

```
GParted 0.30.0 --enable-libparted-dmraid --enable-online-resize

Libparted 3.2
Shrink /dev/sda1 from 465.76 GiB to 201.76 GiB  00:00:00    ( ERROR )

calibrate /dev/sda1  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )

path: /dev/sda1 (partition)
start: 2048
end: 976771071
size: 976769024 (465.76 GiB)
shrink file system  00:00:00    ( ERROR )

lvm pvresize -v --yes --setphysicalvolumesize 211556352K '/dev/sda1'  00:00:00    ( ERROR )

0 physical volume(s) resized / 1 physical volume(s) not resized
Wiping internal VG cache
Wiping cache of LVM-capable devices
Archiving volume group "ubuntu-vg" metadata (seqno 7).
WARNING: /dev/sda1: Pretending size is 423112704 not 976769024 sectors.
Resizing volume "/dev/sda1" to 423112704 sectors.
Resizing physical volume /dev/sda1 from 119234 to 51649 extents.
/dev/sda1: cannot resize to 51649 extents as later ones are allocated.

========================================
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: http://www.microhowto.info/howto/reduce_the_size_of_an_lvm_logical_volume.html may be helpful.  Which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number? Are you using virtualization, and if so, which package? Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question. Please do not use Add Comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try KDE Partition Manager. I think GParted is not able to move used LVM extents. KDE Partition Manager calls uses `lvm pvmove` to deal with your problem.